# How to make ajax request from codeigniter view

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a view

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

function ajax_articles() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/codeigniter/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/patientmain/search_doctor_by_name/"+$('#search')[0],
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: "type=article",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax').html(data);
      }

  });

}
</script>
<div class="content">
<div class="content-left">
<div  class="row1">
   <h2>Welcome <? echo $username ?></h2>
   <form name="search">
   Search Doctor by name : <input name="name" id="search" type="text" onChange="ajax_articles();">
   </form>
   </div>

   <div id="ajax">


</div>
</div>

<div class="content-right">
<div class="mainmenu">
<h2 class="sidebar1">My Menu</h2>
<p><ul>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 10</a></li>
</ul></p>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

This is my view now i want to call the `http://localhost/codeigniter/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/patientmain/search_doctor_by_name` through this jquery ajax. But nothing is happening. No response is coming. I think there is some problem in the code can anyone please point out the problems.  Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: have you checked for errors in firebug..?

Comment: In ajax request, try putting another function on error like `error:function() { alert("Error in ajax call"); }`

Comment: I am new to ajax in jquery can you please tell me where to add this code

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
public function search_doctor_by_name($search_name = '') {
      //$this->db->where('name',$search_name);
      //$row = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();
      $this->output->set_output($data);//or echo 'some data';
}
```

may be you need firebug.^_^

Comment: this function is there and its working only the ajax is not loading

Answer (score 0):

```
function ajax_articles() {
$.post("http://localhost/codeigniter/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/patientmain/search_doctor_by_name/"+$('#search').val(),{},function(data) {$('#ajax').html(data);});

}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

include

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

and use this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").change(function(){
        dataString = $("#JqAjaxForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your ci url",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this

            alert(data);// this will be a json string

        }

        });         

    });
});
```

and give your text box like this

```
<input id="search" type="text" name="name_ajax" />
```

and this is your form id

```
JqAjaxForm
```